# how to find out which site i connect it to when click on link

Tags: php

I'm working on my PHP script as I want to call a function when I click the link on my site.

I'm stored the website links and ids in a database and I want to find out what site i connect it to when click the link on my site, example: www.mysite.com/myscript.php?channels=ABC&id=101.

```
<?php
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;
$link;
include ('simple_html_dom.php');

function db_connect()
{
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('DB_USER', 'mydbname');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'mydbname');

  $errmsg_arr = array();
  $errflag = false;
  $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

  if(!$link) 
  {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
  if(!$db) 
  {
    die("Unable to select database");
  }
}

function tvguidecom($row)
{
  include ('tvguide.get-listing.php');
  return true;
}

function skyuk($row)
{
  include ('skyuk.php');
  return true;
}
db_connect();


function clean($var)
{
  return mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($var));
}

$channels = "";
$id = "";

if(isset($_GET['channels']))
{
  $channels = $_GET['channels'];
}
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
  $id = $_GET['id'];
}

if($errflag) 
{
  $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
  echo implode('<br />',$errmsg_arr);
}
else 
{
  $insert = array();

  if(isset($_GET['channels'])) 
  {
    $insert[] = 'channels = \'' . clean($_GET['channels']) .'\'';
  }
  if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
  {
    $insert[] = 'id = \'' . clean($_GET['id']) . '\'';
  }

  if($channels && $id) 
  {
    $qrytable1="SELECT id, channels, links FROM tvguide WHERE channels='$channels' && id='$id'";
    $result1=mysql_query($qrytable1) or die('Error:<br />' . $qry . '<br />' . mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
       tvguidecom($row);
       skyuk($row);
    }
    mysql_close();
    exit;
  }
  else if(!$channels && ! $id) 
  {
    $qrytable1="SELECT id, channels, links, streams FROM tvguide";
    $result1=mysql_query($qrytable1) or die('Error:<br />' . $qry . '<br />' . mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
    {
      echo "<p id='channels'>".$row["id"]. " " . $row["channels"]. "</p>";
      echo '<a id="link1" href="http://example.com/get-listing.php?channels=' . $row["channels"] . "&id=" . $row["id"] . '">http://example.com/~ytestbox/get-listing.php?channels=' . $row["channels"] . "&id=" . $row["id"] . '</a><br><br>';

      //echo "<p id='links'>";

      //echo '<a id="link1" href="http://example.com/~ytestbox/get-listing.php?channels=' . $row["channels"] . "&id=" . $row["id"] . "'>http://67.23.248.61/~ytestbox/get-listing.php?channels=" . $row["channels"] . "&id=" . $row["id"] .'>test</a></p>';
      //echo '<a id="link1" href="http://example.com/~ytestbox/get-listing.php?channels=';

      echo '<a id="streams" href="' . $row['streams'] . '">Stream 1</a><br><br>';
    }
  } 
}
?>
```

I'm using two different functions `tvguidecom` and `skyuk`. I don't know which site i connect it to when using the different ids. Can you please show me an example of how I can find out what site i connect it to with an id before I could call a function?

Comment: It's not quite clear what information you want to compare with what. What is the "site"? The domain of the link for the database row?

Comment: @ChristianM well I'm trying to compare a website link when I click the link on my website to see if it return to true before I call the function. Here is for example: I click on my website link which it is `www.mysite.com/myscript.php?channels=ABC&id=101` and I connect to tvguide.com site, I want to check the domain name in a database to see if i'm connecting to tvguide.com site then i want call the tvguidecom function to do something. Hope it make sense?